# jqGrid afterSubmit

Tags: jquery, json, validation, http, jqgrid

I am returning a JSON value called **insertStatus** and I'd like to get it from the function **aftersubmit** which I have as it follows:

```
var addOptions = 
      
      { 
          closeOnEscape: true,
          width:500,
          url: 'addMember', 
          savekey: [true, 13],
          afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
          { 
              alert(response.insertStatus);
          },
          resize : false,
          closeAfterAdd: true
      };
```

But I will just display the message "undefined".

I am trying to get the value of InsertStatus as JSON because this value will tell me if the insert of the new record was successfully saved to the Database or not. Maybe I should follow another approach if I cannot get the JSON value from here?

I used errorText before for another task and instead of returning a JSON value I returned an HTTP error status with a custom error message. Which would be the best approach? Even if the second approach was better I'd really like to know the answer of the first one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you mean you wanna get json from your server after jqgrid submit something?

Comment: Hello viyancs, yes that's what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what the response from your server after new row is success saved to database, make sure the response is object because you call with object handling `response.insertStatus`, i'm suggest to you to just `alert(response);`  `alert(postdata)` and update your question include that response results...

i think with this many people will be answer..:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form editing module of jqGrid uses `complete` callback of `jQuery.ajax` instead of typical `success` callback (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L709-729)). So the first parameter of `afterSubmit` callback (the `response` parameter) is object which will be named in jqGrid documentation as `jqXHR`. It's extension of `XMLHttpRequest`. So you should use `responseText` property to access the plain response from the server. If the server return object with `insertStatus` encoded as JSON string then you have to parse JSON string `response.responseText` first and only then get `insertStatus` property. The corresponding code of `afterSubmit` can be about the following:

```
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
    var res = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    if (res && res.insertStatus) {
        alert(res.insertStatus);
    }
    // you should don't forget to return
    //     return [true, ""];
    // in case of successful editing and return
    //     return [true, "", newId];
    // with the Id of new row generated from the server
    // if you would use reloadAfterSubmit: false
    // option of editGridRow
}
```

Comment: Thank You Oleg! That's exactly what I was looking for, you are a life saver! I just have another question. What would be the best practice for server side validation in jqGrid? 1. Return a JSON object like I did in this case, and based on it's value, render an error or a success message or 2. Return a HTTP error status and use errorTextFormat event? Thank you again!

Comment: @JohnSmith: You are welcome! The best it returning of HTTP error status and use `errorTextFormat`. You should take in the consideration that HTTP error status of the server response can be in case of unhandled exception or even in case of timeout or if the server is down. So implementation of good `errorTextFormat` is recommended for all productive projects.

Comment: What HTTP error status would you return when the record could not be saved because the username already existed? (for example) Something like 4xx? Or 3xx? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnSmith: The value of the status code will be not used by jqGrid. So you can define yourself whether to return some 3xx status like `304` (Not Modified), `4xx` like `401` (Unauthorized) or `409` (Conflict) or `5xx` like `500` (Internal Server Error). The choice is absolutely free and should correspond *the reason* (the origin) of the error.