# jquery grid: disable reload grid after editing

Tags: jqgrid

Guys

Currently I found that: the jQGrid automatically reload after editing, how could I disable auto reload grid after editing? as I just want to reload the field that I updated.

Thanks,

Lindy

Answer (score 1):

It should be called on click event of save button and your page will reload with new values:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var address=$(location).attr("href");
 window.location.reload(address);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```js
reloadAfterSubmit: false
```

[option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) of the form editing.

You should be careful with the usage of the option in case of adding on new rows. In the case you have to return rowid from the server and use `afterSubmit` to decode it and forward to jqGrid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13191881/315935) for the code example.